# GA4 events not firing on redirection

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I've noticed that the GA4 events are fired in delay (about 1 sec after universal analytics fires)
This is ok as long as the event fires, but when the event is click on redirection link, the pages are redirected before the GA4 event fires (universal analytics is ok)

anyone knows anything about it?

I'm using GTM to store the event detail, and the click element has a unique id (data-attribute)

Answer (score 1):

You can set tag firing prioritization, in your scenario keep GA4 tag at first priority.

Know more: https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/2772421?hl=en